# 'mat-form-field' is not a known element error in Angular 14 with angular material

Tags: angular-material

I have installed angular material and then imported into my app-module

[image]

Now I want to use a selector of employees so I have this template in my component

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
 <mat-label>Empleado</mat-label>
 <mat-select [(value)]="empleadoSeleccionado">
  <mat-option [value]="empleado.empleadoID" *ngFor="let empleado of listaEmpleados">{{empleado.nombre}}</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

In material module I have imported MatSelectModule and MatFormFielModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';



@NgModule({
 declarations: [],
 imports: [
   CommonModule,
   MatSelectModule,
   MatFormFieldModule,
 ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

But I get always this same error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error was in Material Module where I need export the array not import

Thanks